# Shell Script to add extension on file and directory

Tags: shell

I need help to write a script that will receive arguments that are directories in the current directory and browse that directory.

If found, and it's a and directory the script adds the following extension: `.aaa`

But if it found a file that is `pdf`, or `zip` or `mp3`, it should add the following extension: `.bbb`

We suppose that the files do not have any extension yet

### Example:

if it found the directory hello it should remane it as hello.aaa and if it find a pdf file name myfile it remanes it as myfile.pdf,

Am not sure if should use `case` ... `in` or something else:

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir in "$@"; do
    for file in "$dir"/*;
    do    
        if [[ -d $file ]]
        then
            ext=dir
        else
            file *
            if ???????? then ext=pdf; # am not sure how to set the condition so that if teh file found is pdf to add the extension PDF.
            else
                if ???????? ext=zip # same thing if teh file found is zip 
                else
                    if ?????? ext=mp3 # samething if the file found is mp3

    done
done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell script to add text at the end of Directory and specific files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948542/shell-script-to-add-text-at-the-end-of-directory-and-specific-files)

Comment: You can get the extension using `ext="${file##*.}"`, as per @kojiro's answer to your previous question. Or have you somehow removed the extensions by running an untested version of your script?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir in "$@"; do
    for file in "$dir"/*; do
        # protect against empty dirs - the shell just passes a
        # literal asterisk along in this case
        case $file in
        "$dir/*")
             continue
             ;;
        esac
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            ext=aaa
            continue
        fi
        case $(file "$file") in
        "gzip compressed"*)
            ext=gzip
            ;;
        "whatever file(1) says for PDFs")
            ext=pdf
            ;;
        "MP3"*)
            ext=mp3
            ;;
        # et cetera
        esac
    done
done
```